# Lambda-ize functions that uses variables outside of the function

Tags: python, function, lambda

Given the function that takes `x` and manipulate `x` as such:

```
>>> x = [5,3,0,0]
>>> j = 1
>>> for i, xi in enumerate(x):
...     if xi == 0:
...             x[i] = 1.0/2**j
...             j+=1
... 
>>> x
[5, 3, 0.5, 0.25]
```

And in a function:

```
def f(x):
  j = 1
  for i, xi in enumerate(x):
    if xi == 0:
      x[i] = 1.0/2**j
      j+=1
  return x
```

**I want to change it into a lambda function but how is that possible when it uses an extra variable that not in my loop?**

Without the complication of `j+=1` and considering `j` as a constant I could do this:

```
j = 1
f = lambda x: [1.0/2**j if xi == 0 else xi for i, xi in enumerate(x)]
```

But I need the j to change when it if statement is made. **How can that be achieved in a lambda function?**

Comment: Why do you need to create a `lambda` for this? What advantages do you feel that gives you? A `lambda` is nothing more than limited method of creating a function object in an expression.

Comment: You can't really do what you want, not without **very ugly** hacks with mutable objects and `or` expressions. Readability**will** be severely compromised.

Comment: It's because of a larger part of the code where there're many different variants of this function, and this function is passed on to another to manipulate `x`.

Comment: To give the background, it's from this PR suggestion to convert these functions into some sort of pass-able function into another: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1270

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make `j` an [`itertools.count()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count); each time you call `next()` on it it'll yield the next value in the sequence:

```
from itertools import count

j = count(1)
f = lambda x: [1.0 / 2 ** next(j) if xi == 0 else xi for i, xi in enumerate(x)]
```

This works because you only ever ask for that next value when `x == 0` is true.

However, you now need to *reset* `j` each time you want to use the `lambda`. You could incorporate it into your list comprehension as an extra one-element tuple to loop over:

```
f = lambda x: [1.0 / 2 ** next(j) if xi == 0 else xi
               for j in (count(1),)
               for i, xi in enumerate(x)]
```

All this is *not all that readable*. I'd stick with the `def` function object instead.

As a side note, you could use `or` to replace the `.. if xi == 0 else xi` expression; `xi == 0` makes `xi` falsey:

```
f = lambda x: [xi or 1.0 / 2 ** next(j)
               for j in (count(1),)
               for i, xi in enumerate(x)]
```